# Writing Javascript tests without NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html

I've been struggling with going back to the roots of doing non-node reliant javascript, in  this particular case for a test. Like many developers, i've fallen into the trap of learning frameworks, and in turn have forgotten / never understood some of the basic paradigms with javascript programming.

**The problem**

I'm trying to test a simple es6 script i've created for a collapsible element. It can be tested with a framework, however the script is simply inserted into the bottom of a html file, rather than be executed in any more complex way, and needs to remain functional without a complex procedure behind it. I understand that this is not the conventional way to do this, you could easily make the problem trivial with modern tech, but it's the way i'm required to put this together.

**Collapsible.js**

```
const initialiseCollapsible = (collapsible) => {
  let collapsibleButton = collapsible.querySelector(".collapsible__button");
  let collapsibleContent = collapsible.querySelector(".collapsible__content");

  collapsibleButton.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
  collapsibleContent.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");

  collapsibleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // cast the value of aria-expanded as a boolean
    let expanded =
      collapsibleButton.getAttribute("aria-expanded") === "false"
        ? false
        : true;
    // Toggle the expanded attribute
    collapsibleButton.setAttribute("aria-expanded", !expanded);
    collapsibleContent.setAttribute("aria-hidden", expanded);
  });
};

(() => {
  [...document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible")].forEach((collapsible) => {
    initialiseCollapsible(collapsible);
  });
})();
```

The file is meant to loop through all instances of `.collapsible`, adding event listeners so they can toggle correctly, and closing them initially (The content has to be accessible with javascript disabled).

**1) Module functionality**

With es6 moduling, i'm aware that it's transpiled normally using something such as babel. And with requireJS, I still don't understand whether `module.exports` is going to be understood by the browser, currently it throws errors because it doesn't understand the syntax. Is there a way of going around this? So I can write a functional script to be called in a html file, while still being able to import this into a test file to run tests on? I'm assuming I could just end up copy and pasting it for the sake of having it available is necessary.

**2) Testing the thing**

I'm struggling to contemplate how to test this piece of code accurately. I see a few potential tests:

Given a collapsible html element,

1. The expanded / hidden are correctly set to start (testing the query selector works and that the set attributes are working correctly) 
   **Problem** I don't quite understand how to emulate this without some sort of virtual dom that I can tamper with, are there good libraries for this? Ones that will allow me to create a document htmlelement that I can run the script code on to see the changes.
2. The collapsible button now has a clickEvent on it that matches the code of the example. **Problem** This feels almost like a functional test to me, i'm testing that something happens when I click the button, almost like cucumber / selenium would be a better route for this. There's a large amount of overhead there for something so simple however, is there an easier way to do this?

I realise this is probably around 10 questions in 1, but if you have any feedback / solutions for the problems posed, feel free to contribute.

Comment: `module.exports` will not work. You will want to use `import` and `export` (Ecmascript modules). We build our tests with webpack instead but you can definitely do without.

Comment: 1) `module.exports` is not ES-Module syntax, but CommonJS (the one traditionally used in NodeJS). 2) If you want to test a front-end component, you'll need to have a frontend of some sort. Maybe you could run test directly in the browser, but this wouldn't work out with CI/CD environments. So, I guess, you're bound to selenium, puppeteer and friends.

Comment: I ended up running the tests through mocha/chai in browser and a test runner, seems to work correctly!